# Anonfiles api? Webrequest

Tags: vb.net

https://anonfiles.com/api/help

i want to use there api but i don't know how webrequests work.:S
i have never done webreq before i have tried this and many other things can i get some help here?

```
  ' Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://anonfiles.com/api/")
    ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST"
    ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    Dim postData As String = "file=C:\Users\blaa\Documents\eng.txt"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    ' Get the request stream.
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    ' Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    ' Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close()
    ' Get the response.
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    ' Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    ' Read the content.
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Display the content.
    MsgBox(responseFromServer)

    ' Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, it's a bit easier:

```
    Dim WithEvents client As New System.Net.WebClient()

    Public Sub StartUpload(ByVal targetUrl As String, ByVal filename As String)

        Dim uriString As New System.Uri(targetUrl)
        client.UploadFileAsync(uriString, filename)

    End Sub

    Sub FileUploadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.UploadFileCompletedEventArgs) Handles client.UploadFileCompleted
        Dim response As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Result)

        ' further process your response string
    End Sub

    Sub Main()

        Try
            StartUpload("https://anonfiles.com/api", "D:\index.html")

            Console.ReadKey()


        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Console.ReadKey()

        End Try

    End Sub
```